# Text in a SVG: Rotate a text within a circle on place

Tags: javascript, svg

I have several text in circle (that's why I use  to define circle once). I want to rotate the text on itself in that circle. My problem is: when I perform a rotation of the text, the text in no longer within the circle. How can I keep the text in the circle when applying a rotation? How can I make the text rotate at its center?

Here is the code I have for now:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      width="200" 
      height="200" 
      viewBox="0 0 200 200" 
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
      <style>
        circle{
          fill: #dcdcc6;
        }
        text{
          font-size: 11px;
          text-anchor: middle;
          fill: rgb(51, 65, 74); 
          font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        }
      </style>
      <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7"></circle>
      </symbol>
      <g>
        <use href="#circle" x="100" y="100" width="40" height="40"></use>
        <svg x="100" y="100" height="40" width="40">
          <g>
            <text x="50%" y="60%" text-anchor="end">TEXT</text>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
      var angle = 45;
      var text = document.querySelector('text');
      text.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        angle += 45;
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        var width = bbox.width;
        var height = bbox.height;
        this.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + (height / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ') rotate(' + angle + ')');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look into the css-property 'transform-origin' which should help you to set the "rotation point" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: also transform-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the text and the circle in 0,0 and then move them to the center using transform/translate you code becomes more straight-forward.

```js
var angle = 0;
var text = document.querySelector('text');
text.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  angle += 45;
  this.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ')');
});
```

```css
circle {
  fill: #dcdcc6;
}

text {
  font-size: 11px;
  fill: rgb(51, 65, 74);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
  <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7"></circle>
  </symbol>
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
    <use href="#circle" transform="translate(-20 -20)" width="40" height="40"/>
    <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">TEXT</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Love your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to AndTheGodsMadeLove
The transform-origin CSS property made the trick.
Changed to:

```
this.setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ')');
this.setAttribute('transform-origin', 'center');
```

Comment: You need to test transform-origin for SVG sub-elements cross browser - the support hasn't been consistently there (like for iOS browser)